# How to insert drop-down Spinners <item> to MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, drop-down-menu, spinner

So I want to make my Drop-down spinner < item > get into MYSQL database . 
and when this < item > get into the database , i want the list < item >  is disappeared from the drop-down list . is it possible in my case ? because I make my spinner items inserted from strings.xml .

here is the strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Konser Futsal</string>

<!-- Strings related to login -->
<string name="prompt_email">Email</string>
<string name="prompt_password">Password (optional)</string>
<string name="action_sign_in">Sign in or register</string>
<string name="action_sign_in_short">Sign in</string>
<string name="error_invalid_email">This email address is invalid</string>
<string name="error_invalid_password">This password is too short</string>
<string name="error_incorrect_password">This password is incorrect</string>
<string name="error_field_required">This field is required</string>
<string name="permission_rationale">"Contacts permissions are needed for providing email
    completions."

</string>

<string-array name="android_layout_arrays">
    <item>Pilih Jam</item>
    <item>10:00</item> 
    <item>11:00</item>
    <item>12:00</item>
    <item>13:00</item>
    <item>14:00</item>   // i want to make these item get into MySQL DB. 
    <item>15:00</item>   // when the "submit" button is clicked . 
    <item>16:00</item>   // then after submitted,the next time
    <item>17:00</item>   // they check,the previous selected item is
    <item>18:00</item>   // disappear from the drop-down list
    <item>19:00</item>
    <item>20:00</item>
    <item>21:00</item>
    <item>22:00</item>
    <item>23:00</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="android_layout_arrays2">
    <item>Pilih Durasi</item>
    <item>1 jam</item>
    <item>2 jam</item>
    <item>3 jam</item>
</string-array>
```

and here's the ReserveActivity.java code

```
public class ReserveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spinner1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reserve);


    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());


}

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String firstItem = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (firstItem.equals(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()))) {
            // ToDo when first item is selected
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                    "Kamu memilih : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg) {

    }


}
}
```

or do I need to change how the spinner works ? because I don't have an idea how to make these items get inserted to the database and disappear from the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using .xml file through inserted an array :

                   <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/spinner"
                            android:entries="@array/android_layout_arrays" />
```

Comment: emm , the list is already appearing when i run it , im just wondering how to make these "item" list get inserted to my MySQL DB

    for example: `<item> 11:00 </item>` i want to make 
if i click on "submit" button this "11:00" will get inserted to my db . thus , the next time they open the drop-down spinner, there is no more "11:00" in the list because it's already in the Database .